# GRUB taking configuration file from wrong partition

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, debian, grub

My partition table looks like this.

```
/dev/mmcblk1p1     2048     6143     4096    2M BIOS boot
/dev/mmcblk1p2     6144  4200447  4194304    2G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk1p3  4200448 16783359 12582912    6G Linux filesystem
```

I'm booting from BIOS mode. UEFI is not supported on the devices.

I have two identical devices. On device A grub is taking the configuration from "`/dev/mmcblk1p2`"`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
On device B I copied over the content in the partitions `/dev/mmcblk1p2` and `/dev/mmcblk1p3`.
I then installed grub on device B with:

`grub-install /dev/mmcblk1`

On device A grub was already installed correctly.

In the grub menu I can correctly select the partitions I want to boot into. However grub is taking the grub.cfg from `/dev/mmcblk1p3` instead of `/dev/mmcblk1p2`.

I want grub to be installed on `/dev/mmcblk1p2` because this is my "recovery" partition.

I've booted into different partitions and ran `grub-install /dev/mmcblk1` but it didn't have any effect on which partition grub was going to take the `grub.cfg` file from.
I've also booted from an USB stick and ran the command from there.

**Question**: How can I make grub take the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from `/dev/mmcblk1p2` instead of `/dev/mmcblk1p3`?

---

I have seen [this Stackoverflow question](https://superuser.com/questions/730125/installed-grub-on-wrong-partition) but it didn't help me further.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SU. I think you contradict yourself in your question. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. You frist state that **_"grub is taking the grub.cfg from /dev/mmcblk1p3 instead of /dev/mmcblk1p2"_** but then you say you are trying to achieve exactly the same behavior **_"How can I make grub take the /boot/grub/grub.cfg from /dev/mmcblk1p3 instead of /dev/mmcblk1p2?"_**. If the above is correct then there is no problem right?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. Edited my question. I want both devices to take the grub.cfg from the second partition /dev/mmcblk1p2. It works on device A but not on device B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using flag `--boot-directory` to explicitly tell GRUB where you want your grub.cfg

Note that if you are installing this on filesystem other than your current root you need to either [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) into it or mount it and use `--boot-directory`

Otherwise when grub-install is running it will write code to MBR pointing at \boot on your current root partition by default...

example:

```
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1p2 /mnt
sudo grub-install --boot-directory /mnt/boot/ /dev/mmcblk1
```

For chroot option you can follow example here:

https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: Thanks I will try this tomorrow evening! I'll report back.

Comment: It's working. :-)